# Skype API для php

Tags: api, php, skype

Кто-то сталкивался со Skype API? Реально ли при помощи JavaScript и php реализовать звонки с сайта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просвещайтесь: [SJ200500101en_WorkingWithTheSkypeAPI.pdf](https://github.com/TheSecretCandy/gskypeautoanswer/blob/master/SJ200500101en_WorkingWithTheSkypeAPI.pdf)

Comment: Обновите, пожалуйста, инфу для просвещения. По данной ссылке 503

Answer (score 6):

нет..не реально..100% занимался данным вопросом..
для того чтобы все организовать нужно побыть кулибиным)да и я думаю что таким образом еще никто не реализовывал звонки с сайта..потому что тут реально винегрет)

у меня было задание сделать звонки с сайта на моб телефон максимально дешево..
если ты хочешь чтобы звонили с сайта на скайп..есть бесплатный сервис ZINGAYA.com
у них там есть свои тарифы на звонки на мобильные.. они не маленькие.. а звонки на скайп бесплатны..

сразу скажу..для звонка на мобильные потребуется прошитый модем HUAWEY e156g..как прошивать для того чтобы он научился звонить голосом можно найти в инете..все просто..

а вот чтобы уже сделать звонки с сайта на мобильный БЕСпЛАТНЕЕ.. нужно следующее..один из компьютеров организации должен работать постоянно.. 
тащим приложение SIP GSM GATEWAY
создаем два аккаунта у любого sip оператора ..у которого звонки между абонентами внутри самого оператора бесплатны..
один аккаунт забиваем в зингаю в SIP 
второй аккаунт забиваем в номер куда будет звонить приложение..
второй аккаунт(номер которого мы забили в приложение зингая куда оно будет звонить) забиваем в программу SIP GSM GATEWAY// подключаем прошитый модем huawey e156g(с симкой с которой будет происходить звонок) и вуаля.. клиент заходит на сайт и звонит напрямую менеджеру этой компании..

в качестве бонуса
еще один момент..программа SIP GSM gateway работает не очень стабильно(для стабильности нужна лицензия)) которая стоит 1300рублей)..иногда отваливается коннект SIP.. значит.. делаем еще дополнительную фишку.. добавляем в зингаю переадресацию на скайп и на SIP одновременно..тобишь если SIP GSM gateway работает нормально то звонок идет на мобильный..если отвалилась звонок идет на постоянно включенный skype на сервере к которому прикручена pamela(автоответчик)..
таким образом ни один клиент не останется без ответа.. а пример реализации есть здесь http://yshi.ru/ вверху кнопка бесплатный звонок с сайта..

Comment: спасибо, мне нужно попроще, чтото вроде нажали на кнопку и открылся скайп, но я вроде бы немного разобрался уже)

Comment: @thedarkelf, "нажали на кнопку - открылся скайп" кажется, для этого надо лишь ссылочку callto организовать